# What makes a value unsafe to be stored in a register?

Tags: compiler-construction, register-allocation

When talking about register allocation, texts on compilation (for example, Engineering a Compiler by Cooper) often mention that values stored in registers need to be "safe" - otherwise they should be stored in memory.

What makes a value unsafe to be kept in a register?

Edit: Context from the book:

"In a memory-to-memory model, the allocator must determine which values can be kept safely in registers—that is, which values are unambiguous."

The most informative mention I could find is
"Register promotion uses data-flow analysis of pointer values to determine when a pointer-based value can safely be kept in a register throughout a loop nest and to rewrite the code so that the value is kept in a newly introduced temporary variable."

So to clarify the question: why would a pointer value be unsafe to store in a register, and is this the only case when a value could not be safe to store in a register?

Comment: It would help to provide a quote from Cooper using "safe" in context, and/or looking up "safe" in the book's index.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first quote, but the second one is about alias analysis -- when the compiler can prove a value loaded through a pointer will not change throughout a loop, so it need not be loaded on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it's mostly a matter of `aliases`. Aliases are two or more names that refer to the same object at some point in the program.

Aliases make it very difficult to perform some important optimizations. Consider the following C example:

```
int first, second, *p, *q;
...
first = *p; // store the value from the variable referred to by p in first
*q = 3;     // assign to the variable referred to by q
second = *p;     // store the value from the variable referred to by p in second
```

The initial assignment to `first` will, on most machines, require that `*p` is loaded into a register. Since accessing memory is expensive, the compiler will want to hang on to the loaded value, and reuse it in the assignment to `second`. However, it will be unable to do so, unless it can verify that `p` and `q` do not refer to the same object (that `*p` and `*q` are not aliases).

The analysis done to verify that certain names are not aliases, is called `alias analysis`, and determines when values can be safely cached in registers, computed "out of order" or accessed by concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different bit of code:

```
static int x;
int* p;
int first, second;

first = x;
*p = 3;
second = x;
```

The assignment to *p might have changed x, so the assignment second = x must read x from memory again and cannot use the value that was just stored in first and which is probably still in a register.

Answer (score -1):

The availability of register storage does not guarantee faster execution of the program when you use pointer variables. For example, if too many register variables are declared, or there are not enough registers available to store all of them, values in some registers would have to be moved to temporary storage in memory in order to clear those registers for other variables. And also in this process, it becomes unsafe moving register memory to temporary memory.

Thus, much time may be wasted in moving data back and forth between registers and memory locations. In addition, the use of pointer variables for variable storage may interfere with other uses of registers by the compiler, such as storage of temporary values in expression evaluation. In the end, use of register variables could actually result in slower execution in this perticular case as i mentioned. Register variables should only be used if you have a detailed knowledge of the architecture and compiler for the computer you are using.

It is best to check the appropriate manuals if you use pointer variables that you are going to put in registers.